# SNMP access via c,c++ or Java

Tags: java, c++, c

I have printer HP LaserJet P2015 Series configured in the lan and i have enabled the snmp access in the printer.

Need a way to get output for snmp-mib's ? via c , c++ or java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java, take a look at the [snmp4j](http://www.snmp4j.org/) project.

For C, take a look at the [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) project.

Both projects are open source and provide SNMP client APIs.

Comment: Good answer. snmp4j is very straightforward and easy to integrate with your Java code, plus you don't have to know too much about SNMP. Net-SNMP? Well, that takes a little longer because you need a good, firm grasp of SNMP concepts and operation.